# Can I use CombineAndMinify for asp.net if I don't use Ajax toolkit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, minify

I want to speed up the load time of my website.
I have studied to implement 'CombineAndMinify' dll or package for Asp.net.
My website does not use the Ajax toolkit, so can I still use 'CombineAndminify'??
Or is there any other way better than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine and minify your code in advanced using any program, and then use this static files on your online site, of course first test it and on developer machine.

Also you can make the same think in real time but its require a lot of code.

I suggest the Microsoft Ajax Minifier: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxMinQuickStart.ashx

because I use it and works very well, and also can do the minified not only off line but and online. For make it work online you need to download and include the Ajax Minfier dll (not the Ajax Control Toolkit) that you can get it here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Download.ashx

Answer (score 0):

There is bundling and minification built into the next version of asp.net (asp.net 4.5).

Have you looked into this as an option?

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/06/13/asp-net-bundling-and-minification.aspx

I believe the RC has a golive licence so you can deploy live apps with it now.

Alternatively there is an open source library out there called cassette that can help you acheive this in older versions:

- http://getcassette.net/

Answer (score 0):

This library will handle minification using the YUI library and also be able to switch to CDN. It's an option.